# Binding Non-Primitive types using JsonValueProviderFactory

Tags: json, asp.net-mvc-2

I send json to a HttpPost Rest API

```
[HttpPut]
[ActionName("Device")]
public ActionResult PutDevice(Device d)
{
   return Content("");
}
```

Json sent is

```
{
"Name":"Pen",
"Type":1,
"DeviceSize":{"Width":190,"Height":180}
}
```

Device is defined as below:

```
public class Device
{
   public string Name {get; set;}
   public int Type {get; set;}
   public Size DeviceSize {get; set;}
}
```

The problem is both Name & Type is bound properly by the JsonValueProviderFactory. But DeviceSize which is of type Size is not bound and is always empty.

What am I missing?

I have other similar properties of type Point, Color etc. All those are also NOT bound properly.

I have already added JsonValueProviderFactory in Application_Start of Global.asax.cs

Thanks. Please help.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Difficult to answer your question as you have shown only parts of your code. Here's a full working example:

Model:

```
public class Device
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public int Type { get; set; }
    public Size DeviceSize { get; set; }
}

public class Size
{
    public int Width { get; set; }
    public int Height { get; set; }
}
```

Controller:

```
[HandleError]
public class HomeController : Controller
{
    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        return View();
    }

    [HttpPut]
    [ActionName("Device")]
    public ActionResult PutDevice(Device d)
    {
        return Content("success", "text/plain");
    }
}
```

View (`~/Views/Home/Index.aspx`):

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" MasterPageFile="~/Views/Shared/Site.Master" Inherits="System.Web.Mvc.ViewPage" %>

<asp:Content ID="Content2" ContentPlaceHolderID="MainContent" runat="server">

<script type="text/javascript" src="<%= Url.Content("~/scripts/jquery-1.4.1.js") %>"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $.ajax({
        url: '<%= Url.Action("Device") %>',
        type: 'PUT',
        contentType: 'application/json',
        data: JSON.stringify({
            Name: 'Pen',
            Type: 1,
            DeviceSize: { 
                Width: 190, 
                Height: 180 
            }
        }),
        success: function (result) {
            alert(result);
        }
    });
</script>

</asp:Content>
```

`Application_Start` method in `Global.asax`:

```
protected void Application_Start()
{
    AreaRegistration.RegisterAllAreas();
    RegisterRoutes(RouteTable.Routes);
    ValueProviderFactories.Factories.Add(new JsonValueProviderFactory());
}
```

The `JsonValueProviderFactory` class was taken from the [Microsoft.Web.Mvc](http://aspnet.codeplex.com/releases/view/41742#DownloadId=110348) assembly.

Comment: Thanks a lot. It works. The difference was that I was using System.Drawing.Size class while you had defined a new Size class. I still don't understand why it is working. Also, note that when I defined a new Size class with a constructor, it did not work. But when I removed the constructor, it worked. Can you explain why is this the case?

Comment: @goths, it's because models must have public parameterless constructors for them to be serializable. The serializer simply doesn't know how to instantiate this class,which constructor to call, what parameters to pass to it, ..., so it is a scenario which is not supported. And the `System.Drawing.Size` doesn't work for the same reason: it doesn't have a public parameterless constructor. But you should be using view models anyway so this shouldn't be a problem at all.